# Any way to make a cleaner version of this Haskell IO function?

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I've got this large number of IConnection conn => conn -> IO () functions that I need to execute to setup a database correctly. Now, It's not very beautiful like it is, but I am too much of a beginner in Haskell to make it better.

```
setup :: IConnection conn => conn -> IO ()
setup conn = do 
    setupUtterances conn
    commit conn
    setupSegments conn
    commit conn
    setupLevels conn
    commit conn
    setupLevelLevel conn
    commit conn
    setupTCLevelLevel conn
    commit conn
    setupPaths conn
    commit conn
    setupLabelTypes conn
    commit conn 
    setupLegalLabels conn
    commit conn
    setupTracks conn
    commit conn
    setupVariables conn
    commit conn 
    setupFeatures conn
    commit conn
    setupAssociations conn
    commit conn
    return ()
```

Anyway to shorten it? I was playing with

```
sequence $ map ($ conn) [func1, func2,...]
```

But I cannot get it to work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply collect a list of the functions, map the function application and intersperse the commits.  Then you just sequence your actions and manually call the final commit:

```
import Data.List (intersperse)
-- ... other things

setup :: IConnection => -> IO ()
setup conn =
    let ops = [ setupUtterances
              , setupSegments
              , setupLevels
              , setupLevelLevel
              , setupTCLevelLevel
              , setupPaths
              , setupLabelTypes
              , setupLegalLabels
              , setupTracks
              , setupVariables
              , setupFeatures
              , setupAssociations
              ]
        acts = map ($ conn) $ intersperse commit ops
    in sequence_ acts >> commit conn
```

Comment: I think you have a syntax error there: `do.` (The `.` is the syntax error but the `do` isn't needed either.)

Answer (score 8):

How about just

```
setup conn = mapM_ ($ conn) $ intersperse commit
             [ setupUtterances,
             , setupSegments
             , setupLevels
             , setupLevelLevel
             , setupTCLevelLevel
             , setupPaths
             , setupLabelTypes
             , setupLegalLabels
             , setupTracks 
             , setupVariables 
             , setupFeatures 
             , setupAssociations
             , \_ -> return ()]
```

`intersperse` to stick `commit` in between all the actions and `mapM_ ($conn)` to feed `conn` to all the `IO` actions. The final `\_ -> return ()` is to ensure that `commit` is called at the end of it all.

Comment: Nice, I like the nop to get the final commit.

Comment: I think your `.` should be `$`.

Comment: @Mankarse It was just added by my phone while I was trying to edit, sorry about that

Comment: I was tempted to write this answer too, but doesn't it need all the functions to have the same type? What if one of them returns IO Int and the rest return IO ()? Then the original `do` would work, but this approach won't, because it's impossible to create a list of the functions.

Comment: @amalloy I can't say without more details, but you can always add `void .` where needed

Comment: Neat! Thanks, @jozefg: It hadn't occurred to me that a function like `void` must exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeling like doing some code golf today.  One-liner (well, it started like one):

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

-- | Run a sequence of actions with the same connection, committing that 
-- connection after each action.
runSetup :: IConnection conn => [conn -> IO ()] -> conn -> IO ()
runSetup = runReaderT . mapM_ withCommit
    where withCommit action = ReaderT action >> ReaderT commit

setup = runSetup actions 
    where actions = [ setupUtterances
                    , setupSegments
                    , setupLevels
                    , setupLevelLevel
                    , setupTCLevelLevel
                    , setupPaths
                    , setupLabelTypes
                    , setupLegalLabels
                    , setupTracks
                    , setupVariables
                    , setupFeatures
                    , setupAssociations
                    ]
```

The core idea here is that `Connection -> IO ()` is the same as `ReaderT Connection IO ()`: an `IO ()` that's "missing" a `Connection`.  `ReaderT` allows you to treat `commit`, `setupUtterances`, `setupSegments` and friends not as functions, but as actions that share a common, implicit `Connection`.  `ReaderT Connection IO` is just a monad, so you can just tack on a `commit` after each of the actions easily.